# python: reframe panda pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

DataFrame contains records with name, date (day) and price per rent (rentId) information.
as result of pivoting:

```
pd.pivot_table(table_revenue_day, index = ['name'], columns = ['endAt'], aggfunc = {'price':'sum','rentId':'count'}, fill_value=0)
```

I got the table from the pic:
[image]

The idea to have "price" and "rentId" values under each day segment.
Is it a way to reshape the table as required (showed by green arrows)?

df.swaplevel(1,0, axis = 1) changes only the level:
[image]

Comment: look at `reorder_levels` ; see if that helps

Comment: @sammywemmy thank you. will try to find something there.